# Wacom bluetooth capture connect

Tags: bluetooth, tablet, wacom, events

I have a Wacom PTK-540WL (Intuos4) connected to blue-tooth and everything is working fine except the button configuration.

As for now I'm running a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos4 WL Pad pad" Button 2 "key ctrl z"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos4 WL Pad pad" Button 3 "key ctrl y"

xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos4 WL Pad pad" Button 10 "key +shift"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos4 WL Pad pad" Button 11 "key +ctrl"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos4 WL Pad pad" Button 12 "key +alt"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos4 WL Pad pad" Button 13 "key +space"
```

When the tablet disconnect/time is the button configuration reset.

I would like to setup the buttons every time the tablet connect to blue-tooth.
Also when the tablet a timed out and I need turn on the tablet again.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have not setup keys in Dash->Wacom Tablet, Map buttons... As I know this method and xsetwacom cannot work together.

Also, I use script to detect current application and setup wacom config:
https://github.com/flyasky/wacom-profile-switcher